# The different options for accessing random elements in an array using JavaScript/P5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, p5.js

I am new to using JavaScript and the P5.js library.  However, I have many years of experience in Processing and some understanding of Java.

I have worked out 3 ways that I can randomly access an element in an array.  All appear to work however I was wondering what would be best practice. `

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

var rm = Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length); 
var ri = int(random(cars.length));
var words = random(cars);
```

The first 2 methods are familiar however the 3rd is a new concept, is this somthing that is unique to javaSript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The `random()` function you're using is part of P5.js, not plain JavaScript.

The [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random) describes the ways it can be used:

> If no argument is given, returns a random number from 0 up to (but not
> including) 1.
>
> If one argument is given and it is a number, returns a random number
> from 0 up to (but not including) the number.
>
> If one argument is given and it is an array, returns a random element
> from that array.
>
> If two arguments are given, returns a random number from the first
> argument up to (but not including) the second argument.

The first method is the same as `Math.random()`. You're using the second method when you use `random(cars.length)`. And you're using the third method when you use `random(cars)`.